# Magento 2 placeholder image only showing in thumbnail

Tags: magento2, image, default, placeholder

I have the same placeholder image uploaded for all four options: **base, small, swatch, and thumbnail**. The placeholder is showing fine for the thumbnail on the category page, but when I click on one to go to the product details page it shows  default magento placeholder instead of the custom one I have uploaded.

Any clue as to what could have caused this? I have already tried both clearing the cache and running setup:static-content:deploy.

Comment: In the system > cache management in the bottom you should be able to clear cache of product images.  Have you tried this?

Answer (score 3):

One simple solution is overwrite the base placeholder images themselves in our theme. So create this folder path:

```
app/design/frontend/[VENDOR]/[THEME]/Magento_Catalog/web/images/product/placeholder
```

Then in the placeholder folder you need to upload:

```
image.jpg
small_image.jpg
thumbnail.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a core issue. You can read about it, and also fix it from the official Magento2 GitHub:

MAGETWO-53036: [GITHUB] Base image placeholder issue #4549

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/b065cd3e7201c1f7b0b45efe29020662d15ad9f1